# Laravel 7: Full Calendar not showing events

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar, laravel-7, fullcalendar-3

Please see my code first:

Controller:

```
public function getHolidays($days, $start_date) {

    $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($start_date));
    $i = 0;
    $response = array();
    while ($i <= 42) {
        $tsDate = strtotime($date. ' ' .'+ '.$i.' days');
        $day = date('D', $tsDate);
        if(in_array($day, $days)) {
            $data = array();
            $data['title'] = 'Weekend';
            $data['start'] = date('Y-m-d',$tsDate);
            $data['end'] = date('Y-m-d',$tsDate);
            $response[] = $data;
        }

        $i++;
    }
    return $response;
}

public function index(request $request){

        if($request->ajax()) {
        $weekends = DB::table('working_days')
                    ->where('status', 0)
                    ->get(['day'])
                    ->map(function($item) {
                        return $item->day;
                    })->toArray();
        $holidays = DB::table('holidays')
                    ->get()
                    ->map(function($item) {
                        return [
                            'title' => 'Holiday',
                            'start' => Carbon::parse($item->date)->format('Y-m-d'),
                            'end' => Carbon::parse($item->date)->format('Y-m-d'),
                        ];
                    })->toArray();
        $attendances = DB::table('attendances as a')
                // ->where('leave_cat_id', '!=', null)
                ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->get()
                ->map(function($item) {
                    return [
                        'title' => 'Leave',
                        'start' => Carbon::parse($item->date)->format('Y-m-d'),
                        'end' => Carbon::parse($item->date)->format('Y-m-d'),
                        'color' => 'red',
                    ];
                })->toArray();

        $data = [...$this->getHolidays($weekends, $request->start), ...$holidays, ...$attendances];
        return response()->json($data);
    }

    return view('admin.dashboard');
}
```

Blade File script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var calendar = $('#full-calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            editable: true,
            events: '/dashboard',
            eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
                if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                    event.allDay = true;
                } else {
                    event.allDay = false;
                }
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Tables:

1. attendances

| id | user_id | date | status | leave_cat_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-07-13 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-07-12 | 0 | 1 |

2. holidays

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-13 |
| 2 | 2022-07-20 |

2. working_days

| id | day | working_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fri | 0 |
| 2 | Sat | 1 |
| 3 | Sun | 1 |

I want to show attendances on Full Calendar [https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js]

First, weekly holiday will show when the `working_status = 0` and day is matched with calendar.
Second, holidays will show when it will match the dates with calendar date
Third, attendance will show on other days. If the status is 1 it will show present and if 0 it will show absent. Also, if the `leave_cat_id` column is not equal to null, then it will show On leave, others it will show the attendance status.

Can you please modify my code for this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I just solved my problem. Thanks for asking

Comment: Great you solved it. If you want to make your question and answer useful for others, please add your answer here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Don't overwrite the question with the solution! That way it makes no sense for anyone reading. I rolled back your change so the question is still valid. You should add your solution as an Answer below - that way people can vote on it, it shows in search results, and others can also add solutions if they have alternative ideas. (If you still need to see what you changed in order to prepare your answer, the question history is here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72961915/revisions). And please take the [tour] if you need a reminder of how Stackoverflow's Q&A format works. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

public function getHolidays($days, $start_date) {

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($start_date));
$i = 0;
$response = array();
while ($i <= 42) {
    $tsDate = strtotime($date. ' ' .'+ '.$i.' days');
    $day = date('D', $tsDate);
    if(in_array($day, $days)) {
        $data = array();
        $data['title'] = 'Weekend';
        $data['start'] = date('Y-m-d',$tsDate);
        $data['end'] = date('Y-m-d',$tsDate);
        $response[] = $data;
    }

    $i++;
}
return $response;
```

}

public function index(request $request){

```
    if($request->ajax()) {
    $weekends = DB::table('working_days')
                ->where('working_status''status', 0)
                ->get(['day'])
                ->map(function($item) {
                    return $item->day;
                })->toArray();
    $holiday$holidays = DB::table('holidays')
                ->get()
                ->map(function($item) {
                    return [
                        'title' => 'Holiday',
                        'start' => Carbon::parse($item->date)->format('Y-m-d'),
                        'end' => Carbon::parse($item->date)->format('Y-m-d'),
                    ];
                })->toArray();
    $attendances = DB::table('attendances''attendances as a')
            // ->where('leave_cat_id', '!=', null)
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->get()
            ->map(function($item) {
                return [
                    'title' => $item->leave_cat_id ? 'Leave' : ($item->attendance_status == 1 ? 'Present' : 'Absent'),
                    'start' => Carbon::parse($item->attendance_date>date)->format('Y-m-d'),
                    'end' => Carbon::parse($item->attendance_date>date)->format('Y-m-d'),
                    'color' => $item->attendance_status == 1 ? 'green' : 'red',
                ];
            })->toArray();
        
    $data = [...$this->getHolidays($weekends, $request->start), ...$holiday$holidays, ...$attendances];
    return response()->json($data);
}

return view('admin.dashboard');
```

}

```
<script type="text/javascript"><script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var calendar = $('#full-calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            editable: true,
            events: '/dashboard',
            eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
                if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                    event.allDay = true;
                } else {
                    event.allDay = false;
                }
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```